# Mi pagina HTML no reproduce videos en ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: html5

tengo un problema estoy aprendiendo HTML y decidi utilizar el sistema operativo de ubuntu 20.04 LTS el problema es que al meter un HTML simple no reproduce el video, pero también tengo windows 10 y ahí todo funciona correctamente alguien que me pueda ayudar este codigo simple no funciona, la descarga si la realiza pero no reproduce ningún video

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>video</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video controls>
    <sources src="2.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
    <br>
    <a href="2.mp4" download="2.mp4">click para descargar</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No es problema de HTML, sino de códecs no instalados en el sistema operativo. Visita [esta página](https://electronicssoftware.net/como-instalar-codecs-multimedia-en-ubuntu-linux-y-derivados/) para saber cómo instalarlos.